# PyQt4 Installation for windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, pyqt4

I have downloaded PyQt4 for Windows7 from here: https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

After unzipping the file I've run the command

```
python configure-ng.py
```

Unfortunately Iget the following error:

```
Error: Make sure you have a working Qt qmake on your PATH
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `pip install PyQt4`.

Comment: Do you have SIP installed ? SIP is needed before building and using PyQt4. You can get the latest release of the SIP source code from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download.